# Como detectar o sistema operacional com Python?

Tags: python, sistema-operacional

Como posso fazer em Python para identificar qual sistema operacional está sendo utilizado?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import os
print(os.name)
```

Normalmente é isso que importa, indicar o que você pode ou não usar na sua aplicação.

Se quiser realmente mostrar para alguém qual é o sistema operacional ou se quiser fazer algo bem específico para uma versão específica aí pode usar:

```
import platform
print(platform.system())
print(platform.release())
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/o0KK6e). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yqktvgxo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/IO/GetOs.py).

Answer (score 9):

```
 import os
 print os.name
 #Saída: posix
 import platform
 platform.system()
 #Saída: 'Linux'
 platform.release()
 #Saída: '2.6.22-15-generic'
```

Retirado dessa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854/how-to-check-what-os-am-i-running-on-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

Simples (como quase tudo em Python :p) - As saídas são do teste que fiz no meu SO

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.name
nt
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Windows'
>>> platform.release()
'10'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import platform

#PEGAR A VERSÃO COMPLETA
print(platform.platform())
#PEGAR O SISTEMA OPERACIONAL
print(platform.system())
#PEGAR A VERSÃO DO SISTEMA OPERACIONAL
print(platform.release())
#PEGAR A VERSÃO COMPLETA DO SISTEMA OPERACIONAL
print(platform.version())
```