# Python: Como identificar a raiz do sistema operacional?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como identifico a raiz do sistema operacional (windows: "C:\", No linux: "/"), exclusivamente através de comandos python que valha para ambos os sistemas?

Comment: Se são esses dois valores, por que precisa de uma função para isso? Não bastaria um `if` verificando se é Windows ou Linux?

Comment: Necessito que seja capturado do sistema operacional.

Comment: essa pergunta já foi respondida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167296/como-detectar-o-sistema-operacional-com-python

Comment: @AdrianoGomes ele pediu para retornar a pasta raiz do so que utiliza a aplicação, não o não apenas identificar o sistema

Comment: Consegui senhores. Obrigado. Segue a solução: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/337395/62736

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize os comandos abaixo:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath(os.sep)
'/'
```

Resultados seriam:

- Linux retorna "/"
- Windows retorna "C:\\" (ou qualquer que seja o disco atual)

Comment: Funciona no Windows também?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim

Comment: Não me parece que foi isso que ele pediu. Qual seria o resultado no windows?

Comment: @Sidon editada.

Comment: Ok, para ficar completo teria que retirar o scape, ou seja, teria que elaborar mais, como fiz na minha resposta. :-)

Comment: O escape não faz parte da variável, não é possível "retirá-lo". É somente uma representação visual, que aparece quando se imprime o `repr()` da variável.  A resposta está correta.

Comment: Verdade, coisas do mundo windows, acho que nunca fiz nada em python no windows. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui a solução senhores.

```
os.path.commonpath(os.get_exec_path())
```

A associação dos comandos acima, exibirá sempre o root do sistema operacional (SO), para qualquer SO.

:D

Comment: Se a resposta do @sant0will funcionar em qualquer so, qual é a vantagem da sua solução em relação a dele (mais enxuta e elegante)?

Comment: @Sidon, não sei bem ainda...
Tenho que testar, pois terá que funcionar em diretórios de rede, e multiplas unidades...
Trarei o resultado.

Comment: @Sidon, testei e funciona bem.

Comment: a alternativa do colega @sant0will é mais simples, pythonica e funciona bem!!! É a melhor solução para este problema.